# Alternative for ServletContextListener in webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netty, servletcontextlistener

Since, `ServletContextListener` part of `servlet-api` which is not available in `netty`. Can someone help me for alternative for `ServletContextListener` in webflux ?

**Code**

```
public abstract class AppContextListenerBase implements ServletContextListener {
    protected LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    protected String appName;

    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent event) {
      initializeAppParameters(event.getServletContext());
      appName = AppUtil.getApplicationName();
        

        try {

            doInit(event);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            LogbackConfigurer.initDefaults();
            event.getServletContext().log("[" + appName + "] Invalid logbackConfigLocation", ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogbackConfigurer.initDefaults();
            event.getServletContext().log("[" + appName + "] Unexpected error during logback initialization ", e);
        }
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        
      //clean -up context 
    }


    private void initializeAppParameters(ServletContext appContext) {
        String appNameLocal          = getAppNameFromContext(appContext);
        String implementationVersion = getImplementationVersionFromContext(appContext);
        //some more code using above variables 
    }

      protected void doInit(ServletContextEvent event) throws Exception {
        ServletContext sc  = event.getServletContext();
        WebApplicationContext c = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sc);

        AppConfigurer appConfigurer = c.getBean(AppConfigurer.class);
        appConfigurer.configure();
      }

}
```

Alternative, which could help my application to initialise required service/context at the start-up.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? What is your usecase?

Comment: @M.Deinum migrating our existing application, where we have some implementation which gets initialised while application startup. We are looking for something similar to do in webflux.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, why do you need that listener? What does it do... There are probably better ways of doing that in a Spring application. But without knowing what that `ServletContextListener` is being used for that will be impossible to answer. So maybe you can add that `ServletContextListener` of yours so we see what it does.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, I completely agree. We can use any other method. However, we are using listener for initial parameter value to initialise some service within our application at startup. Those initial parameter could be application property or JVM arguments. We are also running some initial validation for application like checking some specific beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum most likely something which could be invoked at application startup and will have application context to use and initialise service.

Comment: Looks like you are actually working around Spring (Boot) with that listener instead of just using Spring and an `ApplicationListener`. But as stated before, please add that code if you want a full answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum I won't be able to share exact code, but shared minimal code which could hopefully give you some idea.

Comment: You are really working around Spring with this... Make the `configure` method of your `AppConfigurer` an `@PostConstruct` and simply use `@Value` to obtain the values of the variables. You don't really need to replace it with anything but regular spring usage.